# Json formatter online

Tags: .net, json, asp.net-mvc

Is there any API I can use to send a JSON string with no format and got the response with the JSON formated (prettify).

I have a project in .NET Core that get the response from an external API as json without format, so it looks like a big string. I want to do an HTTP request sending that JSON to any API/Service that beautify this and get the response back to display in my page.

Thanks

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: all the questions are about asking suggestions, otherwise what the sense of the forum?

Comment: No, you are specifically asking for an external service, that's not what this site is for. Feel free to read the help docs to see what is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what sorts of questions you should [avoid asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: The forum supposes to help programmers when we need most, not to keep reading a lot of documentation when we are searching answers. Same stuff I do when someone at work asks for my help, I try to help. Great contribution, thanks!

Comment: Asking for off-site resources is considered off-topic for Stack Overflow.  See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), which says: "**Questions asking us to recommend or find a** book, **tool**, software library, tutorial **or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow** as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."  That said, you don't need an external service to format JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to go for an external service. You can use Newtonsoft JSON.net library.

```
private static string PretifyJson(string json)
{
    dynamic objJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objJson, Formatting.Indented);
}
```

`Formatting.Indented` will do the trick for you.

Comment: Also need this in the view: <pre id="json">  @Model.Json</pre>